# Change existing column in PG to auto-incremental primary key

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.3

I have a database in Postgresql, which was migrated from SQL Server (only data).
On SQL Server, a table from this database has these columns:

```
measure_id
datum
measure
```

where `measure_id` is auto-incremental primary key, `datum` is datetime and `measure` is float.
After migration in Postrgresql, `measure_id` is column of type bigint.

How can I change this column (`measure_id`) to bigserial and assign it as primary key, now that my table is full of data?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a sequence and use it as the default value for the column:

```
create sequence measures_measure_id_seq
   owned by measures.measure_id;

alter table measures
   alter column measure_id set default nextval('measures_measure_id_seq');

commit;
```

That essentially what `serial` does.

See the manual for details:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

---

Starting with Postgres 10, the recommended way is to use standard compliant `identity` columns, rather than serial (or bigserial).

```
alter table measures
   alter measure_id add generated always as identity;
```

In both cases, you will have to adjust the sequence to match the current maximum value in the `measure_id` column:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('measures', 'measure_id'), max(measure_id))
from measures;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you just drop a note what does `owned by measures.measure_id` do?

Comment: @zetah: Quote from the manual (the link I added): "*the sequence is marked as "owned by" the column, so that it will be dropped if the column or table is dropped*"

Comment: Ah, all right it's just like a decoration. I mentioned that table already has data, but newly created sequence wont respect already present data and will start counting from 1, which will error on first new insert for unique constraint. So if anyone else is reading this it's more correct to use `CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH x` where x is last row (`SELECT MAX(measure_id)+1 FROM measures` in my case)

Comment: @zetah Thanks for this update. How would you write a query in that case? I tried `CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH (SELECT MAX(measure_id)+1 FROM measures); ` but this does not seem to be the correct way.

Comment: What you're trying to do is : 
select setval('sequenceX', (select max(table_id)+1 from table), false)
Found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022559/postgresql-using-subqueries-with-alter-sequence-expressions

Answer (score 5):

I see that the question is already marked as solved, however, as pointed out in the comments, it is missing the case where there are existing records that already have some values set in the relevant column.

I'll list some other cases as well.

I'm doing this for a table called `products` which is present in the `public` schema. The auto-increment is being done for the `id` column of this table.

**1. For a non-existing column**

```
-- auto-increment constraint for a new column
 ALTER TABLE public.products
    ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

**2. For an existing column that got no values in the table**

```
-- create sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE public_products_id_seq OWNED BY public.products.id;

-- use sequence for the target column
ALTER TABLE public.products ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public_products_id_seq');
```

**3. For an existing column that already got some values in the table**

```
-- create sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE public_products_id_seq OWNED BY public.products.id;

-- set the current value of the sequence to the max value from that column
-- (id column in this scenario)
SELECT SETVAL('public_products_id_seq', (select max(id) from public.products), false)

-- use sequence for the target column
ALTER TABLE public.products ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public_products_id_seq');
```

Documentation references for [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html) and [SETVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-sequence.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this because since PG10 `serial` syntax has been replaced by `generated always|default as identity` to make it SQL Standard compliant, so it changes things a bit. Now you don't have to define the sequence that Postgres internally uses to manage the autoincrement values.

**For an existing column that already got some values in the table (PG10+)**

```
-- Let's suppose we have a table like this
create table my_schema.my_table (
    my_serial_col integer primary key,
    another_column varchar
);

-- With this sentence we convert primary key column to autoincrement
alter table my_table alter my_serial_col add generated always as identity;

-- Let's check the name of the autogenerated sequence, just in case
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_schema.my_table','my_serial_col');

-- Let's suppose the name of the sequence was my_schema.my_table_my_serial_col_seq1

-- This sentence updates the sequence to it's next value
select SETVAL('my_schema.my_table_my_serial_col_seq1', (select max(my_serial_col) from my_schema.my_table), true);
```

Note: last sentence's `true` value is used to tell the sequence that next time it's invoked it should give the next value to the one used to update it with the `setval()` function. So the last instruction would be equivalent to this one:

```
select SETVAL('my_schema.my_table_my_serial_col_seq1', (select max(my_serial_col)+1 from my_schema.my_table), false);
```